# Is there a way to get/calculate the final color code of an object after using subsurface colour?

Tags: color, compositing-nodes

Is there a way to get/calculate the final color code of an object after using subsurface color? I use these codes to find the optimal color palettes for my scene.

Comment: In the Blender Render window you can right click to get stats on the pixel you're pointing at.

Comment: @Allen Simpson 
Unfortunately, it won't be accurate enough